# AJAX PHP LOGIN Page is not redirecting correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Basically I've got a AJAX Login page that is working and everything but when I successfully login I want it to redirect to a page without it reloading I'm not sure how its done as I am very new to langauge. Many thanks

```
index.php
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Popup Login</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login_a").click(function(){
        $("#shadow").fadeIn("normal");
         $("#login_form").fadeIn("normal");
         $("#user_name").focus();
    });
    $("#cancel_hide").click(function(){
        $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#shadow").fadeOut();
   });
   $("#login").click(function(){

        username=$("#user_name").val();
        password=$("#password").val();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
            success: function(html){
              if(html=='1')
              {
                $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
                $("#shadow").fadeOut();
                $("#profile").html("<a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>");

              }
              else
              {
                    $("#add_err").html("Wrong username or password");
              }
            },
            beforeSend:function()
            {
                 $("#add_err").html("Loading...")
            }
        });
         return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php session_start(); ?>
    <div id="profile">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
            ?>
            <a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>
        <?php }else {?>
        <a id="login_a" href="#">login</a>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div id="login_form">
        <div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
        <form action="login.php">
            <label>User Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" />
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
            <label></label><br/>
            <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login" />
            <input type="button" id="cancel_hide" value="Cancel" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="shadow" class="popup"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
    <?php
 session_start();
 $username = $_POST['name'];
 $password = $_POST['pwd'];
 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('');
 $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
 $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 if( $num_row >=1 ) {
  echo '1';
  $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];
 }
 else{
 echo 'false';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection, you should escape your username and password with `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: when ajax is finished hide the login form and using another ajax load the loged dashboard

Comment: It is better to redirect from the login page into the application page and use Ajax within the application only.  The login page should only include enough code to allow the user to log in and possibly offer a forgot password or support link.  That way, unauthorized visitors can not learn anything about your application logic.

Comment: How do I hide the login form? and what time of ajax would you recommend? @madalinivascu

Comment: try window.location.replace("/") !!!

Comment: Ideally you would use Ajax to manage data asychronously (out time).  For example, you could track a web users interaction with a web page (ie. clicking links or modifying content).  Then, in the background, send that data to temporary storage for later use.  The Ajax usage here potentially exposes your application to cross site request forgeries too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I successfully login I want it to redirect to a page without it reloading

As long as the page to be redirected to is on the same domain, or you can set CORS headers properly, and you can deal with relative links, then in your success callback you can replace the entire page's HTML with that of the new page.

You can start another ajax call for your new page, and use `document.write()` to obliterate the existing HTML like so:

```
...
success: function(html){
    if(html=='1') {
        $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#shadow").fadeOut(400, function(){

            // Completely replace the page's HTML
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://example.com/logged-in',
                async: false, // You want this synchronous
                success: function(data) {

                  // This code block replaces your current page seamlessly
                  document.open();
                  document.write(data);
                  document.close();

                },
                error: function(e){
                   alert(e.message);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    ...
```

Here is a demo:

```js
$("#bye").fadeOut(1400, function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://enable-cors.org/',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
                  // This is a quick-n-dirty hack 
                  // to get the relative links working for the demo
    var base_href = '<base href="http://enable-cors.org/">';

    document.open();
    document.write(base_href + data);
    document.close();
  },
  error: function(e){
     alert(e.message);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bye"><h1>Logged in Successfully</h1></div>
```